# How to open first program in group by default?, like in ubuntu 16 with unity

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

I want to change ubuntu 18 config so that, when I have two instances of google chrome grouped in start menu (opened app list), when I click on that group, last used / first instance of Chrome app would open immediately, without second click, to confirm which one of available instances to open

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this effect use:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock click-action 'cycle-windows'
```

You can also do this using a GUI tool called: `Dconf Editor`

Path of the config to edit is:

`/org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-dock/click-action`